# Best practices for variable names using Mongo

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I'm developing an application using Java + Mongo. My variables in Java are self-explanatory, like `realCost`, or `estimatedWork`. However, I'm having a huge number of objects and these variable names are repeating. So, my question is: This increase the size of a Mongo document? Should I use compact names to store on Mongo? Or should I keep arrays of pure numbers over arrays of objects to prevent this problem?